# Android Bitmap Recycle Error

Tags: bitmap, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have an error in my Titanium app with later versions of Android.  I'm creating multiple images using the same filename but with different sizes.  If I remove the sizes it works fine, but if I leave the size adjustments I get a crash saying that the canvas is trying to use a recycled bitmap.  Anybody else come across this or have an idea of how to fix it?

I'm doing this in a loop. If I have the width and height there I get the recycle error.  If I remove the height and width it's fine but the images are too big.

I've also tried reading the file into a blob and creating the image that way to make sure the file is released, same problem.

```
// Create an image
var myImage = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image: "filename",
    width: imageWidth + 'dp',
    height: imageHeight + 'dp',
    bottom: imageBottom + 'dp',
    zIndex: lastIndex + 5
});

// Add image to main view
mainView.add(myImage);
```

Comment: Can you show the code of what you are doing? Are you using ImageFactory to changes sizes?

Comment: I'm using Titanium for this rather than the native sdk.  I've added code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, if I set the image file as the backgroundImage instead of the image, it stops crashing.